# Restore whole system on 10.10 with time machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, restore, python

I realized that I somehow deleted some very important files on my computer. I am working with QGIS and I deleted (in my python system's native folder) some eggs and other things which led to the inconvenient outcome that my QGis is not working anymore...

Luckily, I have a backup from yesterday night.

My question: Can I restore my whole system from that backup?
Basically, I want a clean set up with 10.10 and then, all my installed C++ compilers, libraries for Python, plug ins and so forth back on it again..
Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart, hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> while booting to get to the restore screen. You can pick your backup from there. 
[From support site](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14185?locale=en_US)

Comment: thanks! never touch a running system.... That just went good.